# Freemarker check for date/time

Tags: templates, freemarker

Below is the two lines of code that throws error:

```
<#assign test2="20:56:20"?time("HH:mm:ss")>

${test2?date}
```

The second line ends up with error:

```
freemarker.template.TemplateException: Cannot convert TIME into DATE
```

I know this is expected. But how can I check, if a date variable has got the 'date' value before displaying it on screen? For ex: In above example, i would like to check if '`test2`' contains a `date` part before diplaying it on screen.

Comment: Thanks Mat.I'm just learning Freemarker, so kind of researching all the features.  Do you use string built-ins for date frequently or just the "date, datetime" built ins while displaying the date values on screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i usually do it:

```
dateIssued?datetime("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a")
```

or

```
dateIssued?datetime("hh:mm a")
```

or

```
dateIssued?datetime("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Just make sure you passing into your model `java.util.Date`

So I just use the datetime all the time. Hope this will help you.